# Servidor con Raspberrys

Tags: python, python-3.x, servidor

Os comento mi problema.

Necesito montar una especie de servidor con varias Raspberry, la idea es tener una centralita (un ordenador o una Raspberry) que reciba información de otras Raspberry conectadas por WiFi.

Las Raspberry conectadas a esa centralita enviarían información de sensores e imágenes, pero no vídeos ni streaming, solo fotos tomadas bajo ciertas condiciones. Además, desde la centralita tengo que poder comunicarme con esas Raspberry para darles alguna que otra orden.

A ser posible, no sé si es necesario indicarlo, pero sería muy interesante que, de cara al funcionamiento final, pueda tener en una misma pantalla toda la información que recibo de cada Raspberry. Con una pantalla de consola es suficiente, no es necesario que tenga una GUI como tal, una pantallita como la de los programas antiguos por línea de comando.

Mi pregunta es: ¿qué me recomendáis? En temas de servidores soy muy novato y necesito que me guíen un poco. No sé si será necesaria más información, pero de ser así, pedidla.

Muchas gracias a todos de antemano.
Saludos.

Comment: Si eres novato te recomiendo implementar algo más básico para que entiendas la logica de lo que requieres

Comment: Entiendo que debería empezar por algo más sencillo, pero necesito implementar eso en concreto. Por tener que aprender de servidores no es problema, de hecho, es algo que me interesa bastante. He trasteado un poco con servidores, pero siempre ya hechos y nunca tener que hacer uno yo, de ahí que sea novato

Comment: Justo por ello, comienza a crear servidores básicos y entenderas sus limitaciones, ventajas, arquitecturas, etc. En tu pregunta estas pidiendo opiniones y eso es off-topic aqui ya que solo trae debates improductivos en señalar cual es el mejor. Te recomiendo a implementar algo básico y cuando tengas un problema concreto vuelvas y preguntas sobre ese hecho concreto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mira el tema tiene varias aristas y hay un mundo de soluciones para lo que necesitas. Yo te recomiendo que comiences paso a paso. Primero debería interiorizarse en comunicaciones MQTT (Message Queue Telemetry Transport), un protocolo usado para la comunicación machine-to-machine (M2M) en el "Internet of Things". Este protocolo está orientado a la comunicación de sensores, debido a que consume muy poco ancho de banda. Lo bueno es que con este protocolo puedes comunicarte desde una página HTML (con sus respectivos Js) hacia un script Python donde estas leyendo los GPIO. Entonces lo primero sería instalar Mosquitto (el broker de MQTT) en tu Raspberry:

```
Sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:mosquitto-dev/mosquitto-ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mosquitto
sudo apt-get install mosquitto-clients
```

Luego configurar el archivo.conf de mosquitto

```
sudo nano /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf
```

e ingresar los siguientes datos

```
listener 1883
listener 1884

protocol mqtt
listener 2883
protocol websockets
```

Esto lo haces en dos o tres Raspberry  y comienzas a jugar con mensajes de un script a otro mediante `Python` primero instalando la dependencia correcta `con pip install paho-mqtt`

```
# Este script publica mensajes MQTT
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import json        

client = mqtt.Client()
client.connect("192.168.1.100", 1883, 60)
client.publish("test", 'Este es mi primer mensaje')
client.disconnect()



 # Este script escucha los mensajes MQTT
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt

def on_message_test(mosq, obj, msg):

    print("Recibió el mensaje de : " + msg.topic + " que dice " + str(msg.payload))


mqttc = mqtt.Client()
mqttc.message_callback_add("test", on_message_test)
mqttc.on_message = on_message
mqttc.connect("192.168.1.100", 1883, 60)
mqttc.subscribe("test", 0)
mqttc.loop_forever()

#192.168.1.100 es la IP de donde instalaste el broker Mosquiito
```

De esta forma ya tienes solucionado las transacciones de mensajes entre un Raspberry y otra ya que puedes enviar órdenes de una a todas (todas las que estén suscritas a un mismo Topic, que en este ejemplo es 'test') y puedes recibir mensajes de los sensores.

Cuando domines bien el tema en Phyton pudes pasar a JS con `mqttws31.js` aqui te dejo un link para comenzar

- https://www.eclipse.org/paho/clients/js/

Hay un montón de información al respecto te dejo algunos links por los que pueden comenzar:

- https://ricveal.com/blog/primeros-pasos-mqtt/
- https://programarfacil.com/esp8266/mqtt-esp8266-raspberry-pi/
- https://geekytheory.com/tutorial-raspberry-pi-gpio-y-mqtt-parte-1

Lo de la transmisión de imágenes ya es otra cosa que se puede solucionar con la instalación de un servidor apache y controlando la obtención de fotos desde un simple script JS o PHP

Se que esta respuesta es bastante amplia pero te aseguro que estos son los primeros pasos para lograr lo que necesitas. Espero te ayude.

Comment: Sería super bueno que me pudieras explicar el Voto Negativo para mejorar mi respuesta y esforzarme más en la redacción. Muchas gracias.

Comment: No sé quién le habrá dado un voto negativo a la respuesta ni porqué, pero me parece una respuesta genial. Ahora ya sé por dónde puedo empezar a trabajar todas estas cosas. ¡Muchísimas gracias!

Comment: Me gustaría preguntarte una cosa que no tengo muy clara del código. En la línea en la que pones mqttc.on_message = on_message veo que on_message no está declarado por ningún sitio y, al compilar, me dice que no está declarado. ¿Puede ser que se te haya pasado añadir ahí algo? Muchas gracias

Comment: Si claro que esta sin declarar. Comenta esa línea [# mqttc.on_message = on_message]